# How to limit the number of active streams in RxJava merge()?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm searching for a way to combine multiple event streams with merge() operator and have a limited amount of 'active streams'. For example, when I merge 6 streams (all of them are working on different threads), merge() will subscribe to all of them, but I need it to subscribe to 3 at first and when one of them completes another one should be subscribed to until all of the 6 streams have completed. Is it possible to achieve this with merge or any other RxJava operator or should I write it by myself?

Comment: Just pick one that has a parameter named `maxConcurrency`: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#merge(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the value maxConcurrency in the merge operator, but you will have to wrap all your Observables in one.

```
  @Test
    public void testMergeMaxConcurrency() {
        Observable.merge(Observable.just(
                 Observable.just(3),
                 Observable.just(5),
                 Observable.just(1),
                 Observable.just(4),
                 Observable.just(2)), 2)
                .collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new, ArrayList::add)
                .doOnNext(Collections::sort)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
```